# Count the Number of SelectedItems in `msoFileDialogFilePicker`

Tags: excel, vba, image

Hi I have a file dialog where the user can pick images, after the user has picked the pictures I assign them to images boxes in this way:

```
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .ButtonName = "Inserisci"
    .Title = "Selezionare foto"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
    .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
    .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
    .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
    .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
    .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

    If .Show = -1 Then

    Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
    Image4.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(2))
    Image5.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(3))

    Else
        MsgBox ("Annullato dall'utente")
    End If
End With
```

this code works fine if the user picks three images but if he picks two images it crashes, how can I check if .SelectedItems(k) exists?

Comment: Put the cursor inside the word `FileDialog` in `Application.FileDialog`. Press Shift+F2. Click the green `FileDialog` link at the bottom. Click `SelectedItems` in the right pane. Click the green `FileDialogSelectedItems` link at the bottom. Observe the available properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change:**

```
If .Show = -1 Then
```

**To:**

```
If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 3 Then
```

`.SelectedItems.Count` This line will give you the Count of Selected Items. You can use this to allocate the images accordingly

---

**Something  like this:**

```
If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
    Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
ElseIf .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 2 Then
    Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
    Image4.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(2))
ElseIf .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count = 3 Then
    Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
    Image4.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(2))
    Image5.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(3))
Else
    MsgBox ("Annullato dall'utente")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd like that if the user picks two images it I assign only two images without crashing

Comment: `.SelectedItems.Count` will give you the count. Use it accordingly. @FrancescoBordignon ..See the Answer